# Adding one month to the previous date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I've tried to add one month to the previous month, but I get the 1004 error

My VBA code (this is a simple example but I going to use the for loop)

```
Sub add_month()
Dim d1, d2 As Date
Dim dif, i As Integer

d1 = InputBox("Put the begin date")
d2 = InputBox("Put the end date")
dif = datediff("m", d1, d2)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 1) = dif



Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 3) = d1


For i = 1 To dif


Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, i + 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, i + 2), 1)

Next i
End Sub
```

I want to have in the next columns following values like:
31.03.2023
30.04.2023
31.05.2023
... etc.

Could you help me? I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: VBA has `DateAdd()` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function

Comment: What exactly is unexpected about how it works?

Comment: But the DateAdd() doesn't work as excpected because I don't get the last day of a month:
31.03.2023, 30.04.2023, 30.05.2023, 30.03.2023 etc.

Comment: So you don't want to add one month exactly but you want the last day in the next month?

Comment: Exactly, a user puts the begin and end date (assumption: it's always the last day of the month). Based on this information I calculate the difference in months between the begin and end date and then I want to list the dates (last day of each month).

In a basic example I've noted that I need to press 'Enter' on each cell and then a don't get any errors.

Comment: Maybe you can try using EOMONTH function. Something like this : `with Worksheets("Sheet1"): for  i = 0 to dif: .range("c3").offset(0,i).value=Format(Application.EoMonth(DateAdd("m", i, d1), 0), "dd-mmm-yy"): next: end with`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Sub add_month()
    
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dif As Long, i As Long
    
    d1 = "1/30/2023" 'InputBox("Put the begin date")
    d2 = "6/30/2023" 'InputBox("Put the end date")
    dif = DateDiff("m", d1, d2)
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells(5, 1) = dif
    
    ws.Cells(3, 3) = d1
    For i = 1 To dif
       ws.Cells(3, i + 3).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" 'or whatever is your local date format
       ws.Cells(3, i + 3) = NextMonthEnd(ws.Cells(3, i + 2).Value)
    Next i

End Sub

Function NextMonthEnd(dt As Date)
    'add two months to the first day of `dt` and substract one day
    NextMonthEnd = DateAdd("m", 2, DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt), 1)) - 1
    Debug.Print dt, NextMonthEnd
End Function
```

Comment: This line can be reduced to: `NextMonthEnd = DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt) + 2, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why use VBA?
This is fairly simply done by a formula.
If the input is in A1:
`=IF(MONTH(A1)=12,DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,1,DAY(A1)), DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,DAY(A1)))`